# Showing that a rectangle is equal to the closure of its interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm trying to show that if Q is a rectangle, then Q equals the closure of Int Q. I have that the closure of Int Q is a subset of Q and I'm now working to show that Q is a subset of the closure of Int Q. I understand that this last inclusion is not true in general but I am confused about which property of rectangles I can use to show this. Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: You're probably supposed to use the explicit definition of a rectangle.

Comment: If Q = $[a_{1}, b_{1}]$ x ... x $[a_{n}, b_{n}]$ I can see that the closure of Int Q = Int Q U $\left\{ a_{1},  b_{1},...,  a_{n},  b_{n} \right\}$, am I on the right track with this?

Comment: An example in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Have a look at these two sets (both of which are no(!) rectangles). You can sketch them on a piece of paper.
  $$Q_1:= [4,5] \times \{1\}$$
(one could also write $Q_1:=[4,5] \times [1,1]$) and
  $$Q_2:= [0,4] \times [0,1] \cup [4,5] \times \{1\}$$
Can you tell me explicitly what the closure of the interior is for $Q_1$ and what for $Q_2$? Why do we "lose" points here? Why don't we lose points if we take the closure of the interior of say $Q_3:=[0,1] \times [0,1]$. What is the "cool feature" $Q_3$ has compared to $Q_1$ and $Q_2$? ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I also have to correct your first comment. It's not meant to be mean :-) but maybe it helps to understand. Correct would be for example: If Q = $ [a_1,b_1] \times [a_2,a_2] $, then the closure of the interior of Q would be Int Q U $[a_1,b_1] \times \{a_2\}$ U $[a_1,b_1] \times \{b_2\}$ U $ \{a_1\} \times [a_2,b_2] $ U $ \{a_2\} \times [a_2,b_2] $. Do you see why? For your example Q = $[a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n]$ it would be even longer.

Comment: Oh and just to not confuse you: You have to read $[0,4] \times [0,1] \cup [4,5] \times \{1\}$ as $([0,4] \times [0,1]) \cup ([4,5] \times \{1\})$. "$\times$" is stronger than "$\cup$".

Comment: Thanks, I see why I was wrong in my first comment now. For your example, it appears to me that the interior of $Q_{1}$ is the empty set and so the closure would still be the empty set. For $Q_{2}$ it looks to me like the closure of the interior is just $[0, 4]$ × $[0,1]$. Is the cool feature of $Q_{3}$ the fact that it's intervals contain more than one value? Must all rectangles have sides with non-singleton sets?

Comment: Yes, exactly :-). You maybe did not have an explicit definition of a rectangle but (at least in the spirit of your question/exercise) it would be: A subset $Q$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called *rectangle* if it is of the form
  $$ Q = [a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n]$$
for certain $a_1,\dotsc,a_n,b_1,\dotsc,b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a_1 \lt b_1, \dotsc, a_n \lt b_n$. This on the one hand forbids "singleton sides" on the other hand forbids "infinite sides" like $[1,\infty] \times [1,2]$ as well.

Comment: Now, how does this help to prove your question? You tried to prove $\overline{Q^{\circ}} = Q $ by showing $ \overline{Q^{\circ}} \subseteq Q $ and $ Q \subseteq \overline{Q^{\circ}} $, which usually is a good strategy. (From now on, I will write $S^{\circ}$ for the interior of a set $S$ and $\overline{S}$ for the closure of $S$). But in this case we have have to give the proof a (slightly) different appearance (at least I think so). So maybe start like: Let $Q = [a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ a rectangle.

Comment: Ah I see! Ok so another person recommended that I show that each boundary point of Q is a limit point of Int Q. I know that every open set containing some boundary point of Q intersects Q, but I'm stuck trying to show that all these open sets also intersect Int Q. It seems like this intersection could only have other points from the boundary of Q.

Comment: Steps:
**1.** Prove $Q^{\circ} = (a_1,b_1) \times \dotsb \times (a_n,b_n)$ (by $(a_1,b_1)$ I mean the open interval, which sometimes is also denoted by $]a_1,b_1[$ – not sure what notation you prefer). $Q^{\circ} \supseteq (a_1,b_1) \times \dotsb \times (a_n,b_n)$ is clear (why? use the definition of the interior). $Q^{\circ} \subseteq (a_1,b_1) \times \dotsb \times (a_n,b_n)$ can be proved by contradiction (think of open balls).

Comment: **2.** Prove $\overline{Q^{\circ}} = [a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n]$. Again, one inclusion is clear if you look at the definition of closure. The other inclusion can be (again) proved by contradiction involving the compliment and some open ball.

Comment: **For 1 & 2:** *Definition:* The interior of a set $S$ is the union of all its open subsets and the closure of $S$ is the intersection of all its closed supersets. *Lemma:* The interior of a set $S$ is always open, the closure of a set $S$ is always closed.

Comment: Oh, I meant compl**e**ment, not compliment :-D ;-).

Comment: The steps are extremely helpful, thank you. I'm working on proving the last line of step 1, could you tell me if this looks ok? I assumed (for a contradiction) that there is some $x =(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n) \in$ Int $Q$ such that $x_i = a_i$ for some $i$ (the case for $x_i = b_i$ is almost the same). Then an open ball $B$ with radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$ must be in Int $Q$ but this cannot be since $x_i - \epsilon = a_i - \epsilon$ which is not in even in $[a_i, b_i]$ so it cannot be in Int $Q$.

Comment: Yes :-). Very good. I think now you are on the right track. Glad I could help. Please report back if you have more questions.

Comment: Ok I think I've got it. Could you tell me if I've messed up anywhere? We have the closure of Int $Q \subseteq Q$ clearly (also proved in one of my previous exercises). Now suppose the closure of Int $Q \subset Q$, and let  $G = \mathbb{R}^n -$ the closure of Int $Q$. Then there is some $x=(x_1, ..., x_n)$ in $G$ and $Q$ such that $x_i=a_i$ for some $i$ (again, the case with $b_i$ is the same). Then $\exists \epsilon$ such that an open ball $B$ with radius $\epsilon$ centered at $x$ is contained in $G$. Since $(x_i + \epsilon) \in (a_i, b_i)$ is in the closure of Int Q, we have a contradiction.

Comment: I forgot to note that $G$ is open, since the closure of Int $Q$ is closed.

Comment: @Atreus: You certainly got the idea right but the very last step is not completely correct. As you said, since $G$ is open there exists an $\epsilon \gt 0 $ such that $B_{\epsilon}(x) \subseteq G$. But now you cannot automatically be sure that $x_i + \epsilon \in (a_i,b_i)$ because it could be that $\epsilon$ is sooo big that $x_i + \epsilon $ is "already on the other side of the rectangle" (by which I mean $x_i + \epsilon \gt b_i$).

Comment: @Atreus: Of course you can get a contradiction nevertheless. You could for example write: Because there is a $c \in (a_i,b_i) $ such that $x_i \lt c \lt x_i + \epsilon $ (or because $(a_i,b_i) \cap (x_i - \epsilon, x_i + \epsilon) \neq \emptyset $) we get $B_\epsilon(x) \cap \overline{Q^\circ} \neq \emptyset$, hence $B_\epsilon(x) \nsubseteq G $, a contradiction. Note that the $c$ exists because $(a_i,b_i)$ is not empty (because $a_i$ is "strictly" smaller than $b_i$) which was exactly the "cool feature" of rectangles you observed correctly above.

Comment: Let me just correct two notational errors I made above: I somewhere wrote $[1,\infty]$. It has to be $[1,\infty)$ (or $[1,\infty[$). And further more I am no longer sure that we have the convention that "$\times$" is stronger than "$\cup$". Maybe you have to use parentheses then.

Comment: If you have the time to, you can also write down your complete proof as an answer to your own question here at stackexchange. I was told that this is a good habit to not leave questions unanswered. But I am also fairly new here.

Comment: @Atreus: I now added an answer, also because I realized that one has to be even more careful when proving the second step (see there).

Comment: @Atreus: I added another answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Definition** · *A subset $Q$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a **rectangle** iff it is of the form*
>   $$ Q = [a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n]$$
>   *for certain $a_1,\dotsc,a_n,b_1,\dotsc,b_n \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a_1 \lt b_1,\dotsc,a_n \lt b_n$*.

Let $Q = [a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a rectangle.

1. We claim $Q^{\circ} = ]a_1,b_1[ \times \dotsb \times ]a_n,b_n[$.

   Since $]a_1,b_1[ \times \dotsb \times ]a_n,b_n[$ is an open subset of $Q$, clearly $]a_1,b_1[ \times \dotsb \times ]a_n,b_n[ \subseteq Q^\circ$. We also know $Q^\circ \subseteq Q$.

   Now assume $]a_1,b_1[ \times \dotsb \times ]a_n,b_n[ \subsetneq Q^\circ$. Then we had an $x=(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) \in Q^\circ$ with $x_i=a_i$ or $x_i=b_i$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n $. Let $x_i=a_i$ (the other case is very similar). Since $Q^\circ$ is open, there also was an $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq Q^\circ$. So we had $(x_1,\dotsc,x_i-\epsilon , \dotsc,x_n) \in B_\epsilon(x)$ **but** — since $x_i \lt a_i $ — also $(x_1,\dotsc,x_i-\epsilon , \dotsc,x_n) \notin Q $ and thus even more $(x_1,\dotsc,x_i-\epsilon , \dotsc,x_n) \notin Q^\circ $, a contradiction. It follows that indeed $Q^{\circ} = ]a_1,b_1[ \times \dotsb \times ]a_n,b_n[$.
2. We claim $\overline{Q^\circ} = [a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n]$.

   Since $Q$ is closed and $Q^\circ \subseteq Q$, we clearly have $\overline{Q^\circ} \subseteq \overline{Q} = Q$. Further more we also know $]a_1,b_1[ \times \dotsb \times ]a_n,b_n[ \subseteq \overline{Q^\circ}$.

   Now assume $\overline{Q^\circ} \subsetneq Q = [a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n]$. Then we had an $x=(x_1,\dotsc,x_n) \in Q$ with $x \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \overline{Q^\circ}$ and therefore $x_i=a_i$ or $x_i=b_i$ for at least one $1 \leq i \leq n $. Let $I := \{ i \in {1,\dotsc,n} | x_i = a_i \text{ or } x_i = b_i\} \neq \emptyset$. We now continue the proof only for the case $x_j=a_j$ for all $j \in I$ but the other cases can be treated very similar. Since $\overline{Q^\circ}$ is closed, $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \overline{Q^\circ}$ is open and we have an $ 0 \lt \epsilon$ such that $B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \overline{Q^\circ}$. Let $j \in I$ be arbitrary. Then $ a_j \lt x_j+\epsilon $ and we can choose an $0 \lt \epsilon_j \lt \epsilon$ such that $x_j + \epsilon_j \in ]a_j,b_j[$. For $j \in \{1,\dotsc,n\} \setminus I$ we have $x_j \in ]a_j,b_j[$ anyway. Now consider the point $y=(y_1,\dotsc, y_n)$ with $y_j := x_j + \frac{\epsilon_j}{\sqrt{|I|}}$ for $j \in I$ and $y_j := x_j$ for $j \notin I$. With $k' \in \{ k \in I | \epsilon^2_j \leq \epsilon^2_k \text{ for all } j \in I\}$ (i.e. $\epsilon_{k'}$ has the biggest "$\epsilon$-square") we get
   $$ ||y-x|| = \sqrt{\sum_{j \in I} \frac{\epsilon^2_j}{|I|}} \leq \sqrt{|I| · \frac{\epsilon^2_{k'}}{|I|}} = \epsilon_{k'} \lt \epsilon $$
   hence $y \in B_\epsilon(x) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \overline{Q^\circ} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \setminus Q^\circ$ **but** also $y \in ]a_1,b_1[ \times \dotsb \times ]a_n,b_n[ = Q^\circ$, a contradiction. It follows that indeed $\overline{Q^\circ} = [a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n]$.

Answer (score 1):

Since proving $[a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n] \subseteq \overline{Q^\circ}$ was the hardest part in my previous answer, here is another (maybe easier) way to prove this. You need to know that for a set $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ the closure $\overline{S}$ is exactly the set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n $ that appear as limits of arbitrary converging sequences $(s_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $s_k \in S$. *Sometimes this property is even the definition of closure in a metric space.*

Let $x = (x_1,\dotsc,x_n) \in [a_1,b_1] \times \dotsb \times [a_n,b_n]$ be arbitrary. Define the sets $I := \{i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\} | x_i = a_i \}$ and $ J := \{i\in \{1,\dotsc,n\} | x_i = b_i \}$. For $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\} \setminus (I \cup J)$ we then have $x_i \in ]a_i,b_i[$. Now define for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and each $i \in \{1,\dotsc,n\}$
$$y^{(k)}_i :=\begin{cases}a_i+\frac{b_i-a_i}{2k} &\text{if } i \in I, \\ b_i-\frac{b_i-a_i}{2k} &\text{if } i \in J, \\ x_i &\text{else} \end{cases} $$
and consider the sequence $(y_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ with $y_k := (y^{(k)}_1,\dotsc,y^{(k)}_n)$. Note that for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $y_k \in ]a_1,b_1[ \times \dotsb \times ]a_n,b_n[ = Q^\circ$ and
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} y_k = (\lim_{k \to \infty} y^{(k)}_1, \dotsc, \lim_{k \to \infty} y^{(k)}_n) = (x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = x.$$
Therefore, $x \in \overline{Q^\circ}$.